# lubridate date to weekday conversion error

Tags: r, lubridate

I am currently working to get the name of the weekday given the format month/date/year hour:minute. However the package `lubridate` and the 
command `file1_frame$day <- wday(file1_frame$V9)` OR `file1_frame$day <- weekdays(as.Date(file1_frame$V9))` results in days of the week that are not correct at all. For example the output in R is shown below.

```
Time                     Day of week
4/6/2018 20:14           Sunday
4/7/2018 2:13            Tuesday
```

The correct day is `"Friday"` for `4/6/2018` and `"Saturday"` for `4/7/2018`.
Is this a problem with the package or the R studio? How could I fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order that R recognizes dates correctly, you need to format your date. Take a look into `?as.Date`.

```
library(lubridate)

> weekdays(as.Date("4/6/2018 20:14", "%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] "Friday"
> weekdays(as.Date("4/7/2018 2:13", "%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] "Saturday"
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is a purely `lubridate` alternative of the @jaySF's response. I included `label` and `abbr` arguments for your reference. You can tweak them if you want to work with abbreviations or numbers.

```
library(lubridate)

wday(mdy_hm("4/6/2018 20:14"), label = T, abbr = F)
# [1] Friday
# Levels: Sunday < Monday < Tuesday < Wednesday < Thursday < Friday < Saturday

wday(mdy_hm("4/7/2018 2:13"), label = T, abbr = F)
# [1] Saturday
# Levels: Sunday < Monday < Tuesday < Wednesday < Thursday < Friday < Saturday
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without any packages.  Using `format` from `base R`

```
format(as.Date("4/6/2018 20:14", "%m/%d/%Y"), "%A")
#[1] "Friday"
```

wrap it as a function

```
fwday <- function(date, fmt)  format(as.Date(date, fmt), "%A")
fwday("4/6/2018 20:14", "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "Friday"
fwday("4/7/2018 2:13", "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "Saturday"
```